# How to use beamer environment overlay with tikz-uml?

Tags: beamer, overlays, tikz-uml

Suppose I have the following presentation and want to show umlcall on the next slide. I try to use the onlyenv environment overlay but it does not work with pdfLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen,xstring,calc,pgfkeys,pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A]{a}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}

\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\begin{umlcall}[op=call(), return=ok]{a}{b}
\end{umlcall}
\end{onlyenv}

\end{umlseqdiag}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is wrong?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\only<2>{...}` instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,ifthen,xstring,calc,pgfkeys,pgfopts}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A]{a}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}

%\begin{onlyenv}<2>
\only<2>{\begin{umlcall}[op=call(), return=ok]{a}{b}
\end{umlcall}}
%\end{onlyenv}

\end{umlseqdiag}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much. yes, it works. do you know why \visible and \uncover do not work as \only?

Comment: @AnatolyS `tikz` only supports a limited subset of such overlay commands.

Comment: may be you know how to emulate uncover with tikz? I want to freeze position of visible part of my diagram. /only moves visible part when I open new fragment.

Comment: @AnatolyS That is a new question